# Tax rate for just a few products

Tags: tax, tax-class

I have the following issue and i am not sure how to add it. I have a shop with a tax rate of 24% in all of my products and all customers because i just sell in one country. The problem is that i have to add an extra tax in just a few products of my shop (recycling tax).

Comment: You want to add two taxes for few products?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new tax class in Sales->Tax, create new Tax Zones and a new Tax Rule and apply them to your special products.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed recycling tax, consider adding a [fixed product tax](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-fixed-product.html) to each product. Select the product under Catalog > Manage Products and add a fixed product tax under the **Prices** tab:

[image: Adding a fixed product tax]

You'll also need to enable fixed product taxes under System > Configuration > Tax:

[image: Enabling FPT]